# What’s the difference between “chomp” and “munch”?

Tags: meaning, difference, verbs

What is the difference between “chomp” and “munch”? As far as I know both mean: To eat something noisily.

1) I chomped on popcorn during the movie.

2) He was munching on an apple.

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same thing. Really, it's not so much the noisy aspect I think of with these words. If there's any difference, I'd say "munch" doesn't necessarily imply eating noisily.

> Sally: Whatcha looking for?
>
> Bob: We got anything to munch on?

Here it just really means "eat" or "snack." On the other hand, with "chomp" I think more of eating ravenously - very hungrily and quickly, choking down your food.

I wouldn't probably use "chomp" personally, as it reminds me of a Pac-Man game. But it's a perfectly good word.

Comment: Yeah. I have to agree that they are about as close to exact synonyms as you can get.  Any difference between the two would most likely be minor and vary by region.

Comment: To note: 'chomp' is more casual and US-specific than 'munch'.

Answer (score 1):

Both are onomatopoeia "Chomp" starts with the grinding "ch" sound but has the "p" sound of your mouth closing and is the sound of bite: closing the mouth on food.

Munch has the closed mouth "m" and the "ch" to evoke grinding.  It is more about chewing than biting.

But really this is splitting hairs. In many, or most, casual situations, chomp or munch are close to meaning the same.